# Onmouseenter/Onmouseleave fadeOut wont work

Tags: jquery, fadeout

When hovering the `.f_bb` div, it should simply show up `.f_bloc` and add a class to it. When the hovering is over (when the cursor is out of it), it should fade out and hide. But I can't make it work, for some reason.

HTML

```
<div id="fc3"><div class="f_bb">test
<div class="f_bloc">roat</div></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.test {color: red}
.f_bloc {display: none}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fc3 .f_bb").onmouseenter(function() {
        $(this).closest(".f_bloc").show();
        $(this).closest(".f_bloc").addClass("test");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fc3 .f_bb").onmouseleave(function() {
        $(this).closest(".f_bloc").fadeOut( 1000, function() {
            $(this).closest(".f_bloc").hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ebcm08tL/
**UPDATED** https://jsfiddle.net/ebcm08tL/2/

Comment: Open your browser's dev tools and look at the errors in the console

Comment: @j08691 Doesn't say anything :/

Comment: It absolutely does.

Comment: Not on my browser at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you used `.closest()` method. With `.children()` method works fine to me, and you also have to include jquery if you didn't.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#fc3 .f_bb").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).children(".f_bloc").show();
  $(this).children(".f_bloc").addClass("test");
 });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#fc3 .f_bb").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).children(".f_bloc").fadeOut( 1000, function() {
  $(this).children(".f_bloc").hide();
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.test {color: red}
.f_bloc {display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fc3"><div class="f_bb">test
<div class="f_bloc">roat</div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do it is to unbind any existing events (can assign names) first to avoid duplications:

```
    $("#fc3 .f_bb").unbind('mouseenter.fc3').on('mouseenter.fc3', function (event) {
        // mouseenter actions
    });

    $("#fc3 .f_bb").unbind('mouseleave.fc3').bind('mouseleave.fc3', function (event) {
        // mouseleave actions
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`, not `.onmouseenter()` and `.onmouseleave()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still doesn't work apparently, or i'm missing something. Updated JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ebcm08tL/2/

Comment: You also need to replace `.closest` with `.children`, because `.closest` tries to match an element's parents, but the div you want to display is a child of the div you hover, not a parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `id` to your `div` which contains `roat` text and try using `children()` instead of `closest()` as the `div` you are trying to find is actually children.

Working demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fc3 .f_bb").mouseenter(function() {

    $(this).children("#block").show();
    $(this).children("#block").addClass("test");
  });

  $("#fc3 .f_bb").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children("#block").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).children("#block").hide();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  color: red
}
.f_bloc {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fc3">
  <div class="f_bb">test
    <div id="block" class="f_bloc">roat</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works with classes, i'm gonna use class since there will be multiple f_bloc :p Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think thath your problem is with closest(), i use `find()` to find The class you want

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fc3 .f_bb").mouseenter(function() {
    var f_bloc = $(this).children(".f_bloc");
    f_bloc.show();
    f_bloc.addClass('test');


  });
  $("#fc3 .f_bb").mouseleave(function() {
    var f_bloc = $(this).children(".f_bloc");
    f_bloc.fadeOut( 1000, function() {
      f_bloc.hide();
    });
  });                
});
```

```css
.test {color: red}
.f_bloc {display: none  }
```

```html
<div id="fc3">
  <div class="f_bb">
    test

    <div class="f_bloc"> roat </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks ! But assuming there would be multiple .f_bloc in the code, this would trigger them all, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @mSyx in this cas you must use `children()` , i have edited my answer